# ping to iis hosted web side does not working

Tags: windows, apache, iis, ping

I have a web side hosted on IIS, windows 8 os. I can access from my browser to this page via these urls:

- localhost/mysamplesite
- 192.168.21.10/mysamplesite

I can ping my ip address like this: **ping 192.168.21.10**

But I can not ping to **192.168.21.10/mysamplesite** this command gives error: **ping request could not find host 192.168.21.10/mysamplesite**

Actually have another machine (**192.168.21.45**) that installed apache banchmark on. I want to test request from apache banchmark to my site. So I can not send request.

> ab -n 1 -c -1 192.168.21.10/mysamplesite

This does not work.

Comment: You can't ping a website...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As arco444 mentioned, you can't ping a website, just a computer itself.

ping is the first thing to try when troubleshooting network connectivity problems

```
ping 192.168.21.10
```

from the remove machine.

You can also try [PsPing](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/jj729731.aspx) to test for connectivity to a certain port:

```
psping 192.168.21.10:80
```

however you can not use this to check for a particular resource on your web site.

Instead you have to use a tool to test for http traffic, Apache Benchmark is one of them, depending on the OS on the remote machine, there are many other tools.

If ping works, check the firewall settings on your Windows 8 machine.